# How to persist a multi OneToMany and ManyToOne relationship in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a small problem on persisting OneToMany & ManyToOne relationships.
My goal is when I send a POST request it should send all the data and save them to the proper table in database (MySQL).

I have these classes:

```
public class Demande implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "demande")
    private Set<Contrat> contrats;
}

public class Contrat implements Serializable {


    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEMANDE_ID")
    private Demande demande;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contrat")
    private Set<Assur> assur;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contrat")
    private Set<Souscr> souscr;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contrat")
    private Set<Benef> benef;


public class Assur implements Serializable {


@Column(name = "ID")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CONTRAT_ID")
private Contrat contrat;
}

public class Assur implements Serializable {


@Column(name = "ID")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CONTRAT_ID")
private Contrat contrat;
   }

public class Souscr implements Serializable {


@Column(name = "ID")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CONTRAT_ID")
private Contrat contrat;
}

public class Benef implements Serializable {


@Column(name = "ID")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CONTRAT_ID")
private Contrat contrat;
}
```

As you can see I have Demande Class has a List of Contrats, and Contrat has 3 Lists of different Classes.

As I said I'm trying to make a POST Request and save to database with one Request.
the body Demande has list of contrats and this contrat has multi list

Comment: To be honest, I don't see why your ClassB would get inserted or picked up at all with what you've shown. If you POST a classA instance, JPA should see that you have references to classB instances, but ignore them as you don't have any cascade settings set on the ClassA.classB mapping. Answers below detail JPA cascade settings, but you might want to simplify your questions/models and get the basic working (CRUD operations more than just once) before moving to multi level object graphs.

Comment: And added cascade settings for n some of the mappings, but still left it off the first one in the chain, from Demand->Contrat, why? And you have bidirectional relationships- when they are deserialized from the post call, are they all set on both sides?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to implement the concept of cascade editing here is a link that might help:

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types

You can also manually manage your persistence and keep control by using the @Transactional annotation (I personally use this solution).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have the entities with the @Entity annotation, and that when doing the operation you add @Transactional annotation to open the transaction with spring.

Try something like this, save your main entity and that contains the others with persist and flush.

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA ();
Set<ClassB> classB = new Set<ClassB>();
Set<ClassC> classC = new Set<ClassC>();

classB.setClassC(classC);
classA.setClassB(classB);

classA.persist(person);
classA.flush();
classA.clear();
```

Comment: You would need to add an example of how you do the save operation